# fineuploader S3 InvalidPolicyDocument

Tags: php, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am attempting to upload files using fineuploader directly to an S3 bucket.  I am getting this response:

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code>
  <Message>Invalid Policy: Invalid Condition: missing operation identifier.</Message>
  <RequestId>1760AD72780A2FB6</RequestId><HostId>sg/PvGYzkSySARbo+Ip3r7RomAy8I1O6jHFEjJFbNY9W13fgefKGE=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I've searched all over and cannot find what this means exactly.

This lists the error, but I'm not sure what it points to exactly. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

```
InvalidPolicyDocument The content of the form does not meet the conditions specified in the policy document. 400 Bad Request Client
```

I am following this: https://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/03-setting_up_server-s3.html

In step 3 it says use the below, but I cannot find anywhere what my "server" public and private key should be.  I have the client keys.

```
export AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY=fake/client-private-key
export AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY=fake-server-public-key
export AWS_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY=fake/server-private-key
export S3_BUCKET_NAME=mybucket
```

Looking at the request payload it shows the "key" being undefined so I am guessing it is related.

```
------WebKitFormBoundary2HLrbHuyh80EQFHq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

undefined


------WebKitFormBoundary2HLrbHuyh80EQFHq

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

image/jpeg
```

Any idea what the response means?  Or what the server public and private keys are?

thanks

Comment: Amazon S3 has it's own documentation for php. It was very clear and well written. You might want to take a look.

Comment: Yes I've looked around but cannot find exactly what this error indicates.  Nor can I find server keys the fineuploader docs reference.  It says in step 3 that the keys are created in step 1 but I'm not seeing them.